# SELECT *, COUNT(*) in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

If i perform a standard query in SQLite:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

I get all records in my table as expected. If i perform following query:

```
SELECT *, 1 FROM my_table
```

I get all records as expected with rightmost column holding '1' in all records. But if i perform the query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM my_table
```

I get only ONE row (with rightmost column is a correct count).
Why is such results? I'm not very good in SQL, maybe such behavior is expected? It seems very strange and unlogical to me :(.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM my_table` is not what you want, and it's not really valid SQL, you have to group by all the columns that's not an aggregate.

You'd want something like

```
SELECT somecolumn,someothercolumn, COUNT(*) 
   FROM my_table 
GROUP BY somecolumn,someothercolumn
```

Comment: SQLite help on aggregate functions (sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) don't have anything about 'group by' :(. Is it some documentation i can read about this restriction for better understanding?

Comment: @Eye of Hell any book on SQL would do, it's nothing sqlite specific.

Comment: this answer lead me to this page of the SQLite documentation on resultsets, including GROUP BY: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset

Answer (score 19):

If you want to count the number of records in your table, simply run:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 10):

**count(*)** is an aggregate function. Aggregate functions need to be grouped for a meaningful results. You can read: [count columns group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698108/count-columns-group-by)

Comment: SQLite help on aggregate functions (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) don't have anything about 'group by' :(. Is it some documentation i can read about this restriction for better understanding?

Comment: The SQLite documentation does say "in a group" / "in the group". I suggest to read a tutorial or a book about SQL.

Comment: @EyeofHell only count() is the aggregate function GROUP BY is regular a part of SELECT syntax. http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Answer (score 5):

If what you want is the total number of records in the table appended to each row you can do something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT_OF_RECS_IN_MY_TABLE
                FROM MY_TABLE)
```