# sqlite count of distinct occurrences

Tags: sql, sqlite

What is the best way of writing a sqlite query that will count the occurrences of colC after selecting distinct colA's ?

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC FROM myTable WHERE colA IN ('121', '122','123','124','125','126','127','128','129');
```

Notice ColA needs to be distinct.

[image: Example]

Although close, these results are incorrect.

[image]

It should return:
123 a cat 1
124 b dog 1
125 e snake 2
126 f fish 1
127 g snake 2

Comment: Umm the second table contains the desired results?

Comment: How do you choose `colB` and `colC`?

Comment: I choose it with the select statement above.

Comment: why "dog" in second row of desired result, but not "bird"? what to do with "bird"?

Comment: It does not matter if b dog, c dog, or d bird are chosen... Any ONE of them will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT colA, min(colB) AS colB, max(colC) AS colC
    FROM myTable
    WHERE colA IN ('121', '122','123','124','125','126','127','128','129')
    GROUP BY colA
)
SELECT t.*, c.colC_count
  FROM t
  JOIN (
    SELECT colC, count(*) AS colC_count
      FROM t
      GROUP BY colC
  ) c ON c.colC = t.colC
```

*Explanation:*

First subquery (inside `WITH`) gets desired result but without count column. Second subquery (inside `JOIN`) counts each `colC` value repetition in desired result and this count is returned to final result.

There very helpful `WITH` clause as result of first subquery is used in two places. More info: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

---

Query for SQLite before version 3.8.3:

```
SELECT t.*, c.colC_count
  FROM (
    SELECT colA, min(colB) AS colB, max(colC) AS colC
      FROM myTable
      WHERE colA IN ('121', '122','123','124','125','126','127','128','129')
      GROUP BY colA
    ) t
  JOIN (
    SELECT colC, count(*) AS colC_count
      FROM (
        SELECT max(colC) AS colC
          FROM myTable
          WHERE colA IN ('121', '122','123','124','125','126','127','128','129')
          GROUP BY colA
        ) c
      GROUP BY colC
  ) c ON c.colC = t.colC
```

Comment: This is valid SQLite syntax; see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html; tested with [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

Comment: Looks like you use old SQLite version, as `WITH` clause is introduced in 3.8.3 version: http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_8_3

Comment: Is there a way to produce the correct results without it? See my edit

Comment: Got it... Thank you. Is there a way of assigning ('121', '122','123','124','125','126','127','128','129') to a var so it doesn't have to be entered twice. It is a very long list.

Answer (score 4):

You can aggregate by `colA` to get most of what you want:

```
select colA, count(*)
from myTable
where colA in ('121', '122','123','124','125','126','127','128','129')
group by colA;
```

It is unclear how you are getting `colB` and `colC`.  The following works for your example data:

```
select colA, min(colB), max(colC), count(*)
from myTable
where colA in ('121', '122','123','124','125','126','127','128','129')
group by colA;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon.  Here are the results. 124 should have a 1 count and 125 and 127 should have a 2 count. http://i.imgur.com/dW39SL2.png

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a combination of both [COUNT(colC)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) + [GROUP BY (colA)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp). Something like this:

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC, COUNT(colC)
FROM myTable
WHERE colA IN ('121', '122','123','124','125','126','127','128','129')
GROUP BY (colA);
```

See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615651/1795530).

Comment: Same results as Gordon. 124 should have a 1 count and 125 and 127 should have a 2 count.  http://i.imgur.com/Mc33MSq.png