# Get a count of the number of times distinct entries occur in database query (Android)

Tags: android, distinct

I have a bit of a tricky problem.  My app inputs user data into the SQLite database and I have managed to write queries to get the data back out.

This includes a query that gets a list of distinct values, an example may be as follows. Say you have the following data:

```
Column a  |  Column b  | Column c
   a            a           a
   a            b           b
   a            b           b
   b            b           b
```

Using the 'group by' function, the query would create the following list:

```
aaa
abb
bbb
```

So what I am trying, but failing to do is expand this and get a count of the number of times each distinct entry occurs - so in the above case it would look like this:

```
1 x aaa
2 x abb
1 x bbb
```

So is there a way, once you have queried the database, to get a count of the occurancies of each distinct entry, from the Cursor - or do I need to write a seperate query to get this information..

Here is my query as it looks at the moment:

```
public Cursor fetchDamagedComponentSpecForInspection(long inspectionId, String componentType) {
    Cursor mCursor = rmDb.query(true, DAMAGED_COMPONENTS_TABLE, new String[] {
            DAMAGED_COMPONENT_ID,
            LOCATION_LINK,
            RUN_LINK,
            AREA_LINK,
            INSPECTION_LINK,
            LOCATION_REF,
            RACKING_SYSTEM,
            COMPONENT,
            COMPONENT_TYPE,
            QUANTITY,
            POSITION,
            RISK,
            ACTION_REQUIRED,
            NOTES_GENERAL,
            MANUFACTURER,
            TEXT1,
            TEXT2,
            TEXT3,
            TEXT4,
            NOTES_SPEC,
            SPEC_SAVED}, 
            INSPECTION_LINK + " = " + inspectionId + " AND " + COMPONENT_TYPE + " = ? AND " + SPEC_SAVED + " = ? ", 
            new String[] {componentType, "Yes"},
            MANUFACTURER + ", " + TEXT1 + ", " + TEXT2 + ", " + TEXT3 + ", " + TEXT4 + ", " + NOTES_SPEC,
            null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

For additional information, here is the code in my main activity where I call the query and retrieve the data:

```
final Cursor componentsAndSpecCursor = (Cursor) rmDbHelper.fetchComponentsAndSpecForManufacturer(inspectionId, rackingSystem, manufacturer);
                if(componentsAndSpecCursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do {
                        componentType = componentsAndSpecCursor.getString(componentsAndSpecCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.COMPONENT_TYPE));
                        specText1 = componentsAndSpecCursor.getString(componentsAndSpecCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.TEXT1));
                        specText2 = componentsAndSpecCursor.getString(componentsAndSpecCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.TEXT2));
                        specText3 = componentsAndSpecCursor.getString(componentsAndSpecCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.TEXT3));
                        specText4 = componentsAndSpecCursor.getString(componentsAndSpecCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.TEXT4));
                        specNotes = componentsAndSpecCursor.getString(componentsAndSpecCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.NOTES_SPEC));
                        message.append(componentType).append(" ").append(specText1).append(" ").append(specText2).append(" ").append(specText3).append(" ").append(specText4).append(" ").append(specNotes).append("\r\n");
                    }
                    while (componentsAndSpecCursor.moveToNext());
                }
                componentsAndSpecCursor.close();
```

So I am also unaware of how I would get the Count once I have included this bit of code in my query (which I still can't see how it is done!).

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you are using for the `group by`?

Comment: Hi Gordon, it is in the above query - see the line that states: MANUFACTURER + ", " + TEXT1 + ", " + TEXT2 + ", " + TEXT3 + ", " + TEXT4 + ", " + NOTES_SPEC, - this is the group by variable (you leave in null if you don't want to group by).

Answer (score 1):

Did u try adding `COUNT(*)` function to your columns list?

see this: [count columns group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698108/count-columns-group-by)

Comment: Hi Ovi, thanks for suggestion.  I did see this but I can't work out where I should I add this into my query..

Comment: Ahh yes i was thinking about this. Scamparelli, have a look at the group by and count sql commands

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I'm still at a loss to where in the database.query statement I am using you would stick the COUNT(*) bit..

Comment: You can pass `"Count(*)"` in the selection array `new String[] { "Count(*)", DAMAGED_COMPONENT_ID, LOCATION_LINK, etc` or pass Gordon Linoff's query as a String to [`rawQuery()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29)

Answer (score 1):

The query that you want is:

```
select count(*) as cnt, cola, colb, colc
from YourTable
group by cola, colb, colc
```

I'm not sure how to put this into your code.  You don't seem to have a query that returns the combinations in the snippet of code that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Get all unique values and temporarily store them somewhere and just loop and do another query to try and find those values again and every time u find one, update some counter.

Comment: Hi Jonney, thanks for the quick response. I'm sure this is basic stuff but I haven't done this before - should I use an array to do this and if so is there a correct method of doing this?

Comment: Use a List and create a pojo class of the data you want to store with getters and setters and just add the distinct data objects into your List<Pojo> and then after that you can do the above